# Adding new object in local storage overwrites the old ones

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
   
var  product,    
   numberof,   
   quantity,  
   price,  
   localStorageProd;

function storeProdStorage( product , numberof, quantity, price ) {
    var itemsArray = [];
    newItem = {
      product : product ,
      numberof : numberof ,
      quantity : quantity ,
      price : price 
    };
  
    if (localStorage["prodbank"] != null) {
      var localStorageContentObject = JSON.parse(localStorage["prodbank"]);
      itemsArray.push(localStorageContentObject);

      for( var i = 0; i < itemsArray.length ; i++ ) {
        if(itemsArray[i].product == product) {
            itemsArray[i].quantity = quantity; 
            itemsArray[i].price = price;
            localStorage.setItem('prodbank', JSON.stringify(itemsArray[i]));  
        } else {
          itemsArray.push(newItem);
        localStorage.setItem('prodbank', JSON.stringify(itemsArray));  
        }
      }    
            
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('prodbank', JSON.stringify(newItem));  
    }
}  
  
$(function() {
    $(".quantity-slider").slider({
        range: "min",     
        value: 50,
        min: 50,
        max: 1000,
        step: 50,
        
        slide: function(e,ui) { 
          var quant = $('.quantity').html(commaSeparateNumber((ui.value) *10)); 
          var price = $('.price').html(ui.value);
             if($('.price').html() == "50" ) {
                $('.quantity').html(250);
             }
      
       product = $(".pricing-title").html();
       numberof = $(".pricing-code .form-section h3").contents().get(0).nodeValue;  
       quantity = $(".pricing-code .form-section h3 .quantity").eq(0).html();  
       price = $(".pricing-code .form-section h3 .price").eq(0).html();
          
       storeProdStorage(product , numberof, quantity, price );
     } 
    });

    $('.quantity').html(($( ".quantity-slider" ).slider("value"))*5);
});
```

[image]

I have a range slider which values I'm storing inside objects which are pushed in array and stored in the localStorage. This is the format in which I want to push them inside the localStorage.

[

```
{ "product":"Twitter Followers","numberof":"Number of Followers: ","quantity":"5,500","price":"550" },
{ "product":"Facebook Page Likes","numberof":"Number of Likes: ","quantity":"1,000","price":"100" },
{ "product":"Instagram Followers","numberof":"Number of Followers: ","quantity":"2,500","price":"250" },
{ "..":"..","..":"..: ","..":"..","..":".." }
```

]

Every time the range slider moves I check for the new coming values by the name of the product the user is trying to buy e.g "Facebook Page Likes","Instagram Followers"  . If the name is the same I'm just trying to update the values for the quantity and the price in the local storage . If the name doesn't exist in the local storage I want to add it inside. The problem is that everything turns into a mess. When I move the slider it actually updates the values in the local storage when it's lets say on "Facebook Page Likes" page, but when I go to another (e.g "Twitter Followers") when I move the slider the new object with values overwrite the old ones and doesn't add to the previous ones.

This is example of what i get in the console when navigate through the pages and run the slider . Everytime only one object is preserved in the local storage and the previous is completely removed.

Storage {prodbank: "{"product":"Facebook Page Likes","numberof":"Number of Likes: ","quantity":"1,000","price":"100"}", length: 1}

I want it to add and preserve the values of the old object not to remove it completely. This is what I want for example. Here you can see that the second object with the values for twitter followers exists and it's added inside the storage

Storage {prodbank: "{"product":"Facebook Page Likes","numberof":"Number of Likes: ","quantity":"1,000","price":"100"}",
"{"product":"Twitter Followrs","numberof":"Number of Followers: ","quantity":"2,000","price":"200"}", length: 2}

Answer (score 2):

If you want the new values to be added instead of overwritten, you need to use `+=` instead of `=`. That is because `+=` will add the right-hand value to the left hand value while `=` will replace the left-hand value with the right-hand value

Try:

```
itemsArray[i].quantity  +=  quantity; 
itemsArray[i].price     +=  price;
```

That is if my understanding of what you are trying to achieve is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for. The values of every object are calculated correctly(they are not the problem). It's not about calculation.  I want to add every new object which doesn't exist in the local storage , but it doesn't happen. Actually it's been added but it overwrites the old one. I edited the question with the last four paragraphs, because it's misleading